# UICollectionView showing wrong data on Scroll forward and back?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am using a `UICollectionView`. Inside this View one of my cells has a size of 1000*600(showing one cell in screen).
In my `UICollectionViewCell` are 4 `UILabels` and two `tableViews`.
The data which I am passing to `UILabels` is not showing correctly and as soon as I scroll back the data does not retain. I have seen various example in which it was suggested to use block Operation.
Which approach I have to use? Please help.

Here is the code:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

ToursCollectionViewCell *collectionViewCell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"collectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath ];



UILabel *artistOne=(UILabel*)[self.collectionView viewWithTag:1111];
artistOne.text=[artistNameOneArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UILabel *venueOne=(UILabel*)[self.collectionView viewWithTag:1212];
venueOne.text=[venueLocationOneArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

UILabel *artistTwo=(UILabel*)[self.collectionView viewWithTag:2121];
artistTwo.text=[artistNameTwoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UILabel *venueTwo=(UILabel*)[self.collectionView viewWithTag:2222];
venueTwo.text=[venueLocationTwoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



return collectionViewCell;
```

}

Comment: I don't see any bugs in the code you posted, you must be doing something wrong elsewhere. Can you post more code? No need to use a block operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UILabel *artistOne=(UILabel*)[self.collectionView viewWithTag:1111];
```

should probably be

```
UILabel *artistOne=(UILabel*)[collectionViewCell viewWithTag:1111];
```

(and similarly for the other labels) because the labels are subviews of each
individual *cell* and not of the entire collection view.

Comment: It is not taking UICollectionViewCell

Comment: @user3422834: The "self." was wrong, I have corrected the answer.

Comment: as i am using Two table views in my collectionViewCell if i want to remove Second tableView if (artistTwo.text isEqualTo=@""){}
Then how to achieve this?
It is showing some weired behaiviour.

Comment: @user3422834: Better ask a new question and show the relevant code.